# Conditionally rendering NuxtJS component based on viewport

Tags: vue.js, responsive, nuxt.js

I wonder how conditionally rendering `NuxtJs` components based on viewport width.

so;

in traditional css way we can make it like that:

```
<div class="isMobile">
<!-- mobile content -->
</div>

<div class="isDesktop">
<!-- desktop content -->
</div>
```

in this case this solution working.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .isDesktop {display:none;}
  .isMobile {display:block}
}
```

But with this solution isDesktop and isMobile divs rendered in dom anyway.

I wan't to do that:

```
  <div v-if="isMobile"></div>
    <div v-if="isDesktop"></div>
```

and control this in beforeMount component, or if user will resize window.

I see some plugin like [https://github.com/dotneet/nuxt-device-detect][1]
but there is not understandable readme for me.

anybody have some suggestions?

Comment: I have been struggling with the same. The approach that I have settled for is to do the user agent detection to "guess" the isMobile flag by reading the user agent on context.req.headers on NuxtServerInit. After that I have a hook on the app actually loading to read the screensize and I change my guess. This approach has some caveats. More info here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1053.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot detect the view width from the server, because... well... it is the server. nuxt-device-detect uses the user agent to figure out what kind of device is requesting a page and sets some predefined variables based on that.

Using `$device.isMobile` and `$device.isDesktop` in a `v-if` will make sure that you only serve the DOM nodes you want to serve for mobile and desktop. It will however not respond to resizing the browser. Detection is, after all, done based on user agent and not on view width.

Comment: It's a written on readme of this component but nothing understanding for me.. there is no have any example also

Comment: o sorry i figure out with this. Just add to nuxt config this line and everything work well    {defaultUserAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LYZ28E) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.39 Mobile Safari/537.36'}